# Temporary shutdown of autovacuum during rush hour

Tags: postgresql, performance, autovacuum, cron

I have been asked to **temporarily** disable **autovacuum** in PostgreSQL 14.3. From 7 a.m. to 5 p.m., autovacuum is to be turned off, and at other times it is to be turned back on. I intend to achieve this by setting the command

```shell
psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET autovacuum = off;" && psql -c "SELECT PG_RELOAD_CONF();""
```

and

```shell
psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET autovacuum = on;" && psql -c "SELECT PG_RELOAD_CONF();""
```

using `cron` at appropriate times. I checked this solution on a test database - everything works as it should.

Is there any risks associated with such a solution on the production database? The solution is designed to eliminate performance problems during peak hours.

Comment: [Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78087129/6464308) and answered on Stackoverflow. Please don't post the same question in multiple fora.